# Were fall foliage leaf colors in Canada also delayed in autumn 2021?

Tags: botany, trees

English is not my first language. I didn't fully grok this [National Geographic article](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/environment/article/fall-foliage-disrupted-by-climate-change-might-be-new-normal?utm_source=pocket-newtab) published November 24 2021 by Sarah Gibbens. **But it discusses just the eastern U.S.A., NOT Canada.** How ever ***what about [fall foliage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autumn_leaf_color) in Canada in 2021? Also delayed?***

The sub heading is

> Throughout the eastern U.S., fall colors arrived behind schedule, which scientists say is a sign of things to come.

In the middle

> From [Vermont](https://matttsweatherrapport.blogspot.com/2021/10/later-foliage-seasons-and-pollys.html) to [North Carolina](https://blueridgemountainlife.com/fall-foliage/#tab-con-14), fall foliage appeared behind schedule this year—continuing a long-term trend that, according to one recent study of maples by researchers at George Mason University, has pushed the appearance of fall colors back more than a month since the 19th century.

Comment: Anecdotally, I thought they were.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You can't assume anything (expect [parochialism](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/parochialism) based on a magazine published in the US not talking about things happening outside the US. Please [edit] your question to tel us where you looked and what you found when you do to tried looking this up. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details about this site and expectations for posts.